# Excel VBA, Time values via time picker

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have created a userform where the user has to put in some time values, these time values are for example how long a product has to be processed for. I have a code that is almost what I would like it to do, only when it reaches 24 hours, it resets to 0. but the input requires to be for 24+ hours (for example: 36:59:59 (where the max value of mm & ss = 59, the hh max value should be 99).

could anyone assist me on how I can change this?

```
    Private mtmPosition1 As tmPosition1

Private Const msFMTTIME1 As String = "[$-409]hh:mm:ss"
Private Const miRIGHTARROW1 As Integer = 39
Private Const miLEFTARROW1 As Integer = 37

Private Const mdHOUR1 As Double = 1 / 24
Private Const mdMINUTE1 As Double = 1 / 24 / 60
Private Const mdSECOND1 As Double = 1 / 24 / 60 / 60


Private Enum tmPosition1
    tmPositionHour1
    tmPositionMinute1
    tmPositionSecond1

End Enum

Private Sub sbTime1_SpinDown()
    
    If Me.IsHour1 Then
        Me.tbxTimePicker1.Text = Format(1 + TimeValue(Me.tbxTimePicker1.Text) - mdHOUR1, msFMTTIME1)
        SelectHour1
    ElseIf Me.IsMinute1 Then
        Me.tbxTimePicker1.Text = Format(1 + TimeValue(Me.tbxTimePicker1.Text) - mdMINUTE1, msFMTTIME1)
        SelectMinute1
    ElseIf Me.IsSecond1 Then
        Me.tbxTimePicker1.Text = Format(1 + TimeValue(Me.tbxTimePicker1.Text) - mdSECOND1, msFMTTIME1)
        SelectSecond1

    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub sbTime1_SpinUp()

    If Me.IsHour1 Then
        Me.tbxTimePicker1.Text = Format(1 + TimeValue(Me.tbxTimePicker1.Text) + mdHOUR1, msFMTTIME1)
        SelectHour1
    ElseIf Me.IsMinute1 Then
        Me.tbxTimePicker1.Text = Format(1 + TimeValue(Me.tbxTimePicker1.Text) + mdMINUTE1, msFMTTIME1)
        SelectMinute1
    ElseIf Me.IsSecond1 Then
        Me.tbxTimePicker1.Text = Format(1 + TimeValue(Me.tbxTimePicker1.Text) + mdSECOND1, msFMTTIME1)
        SelectSecond1

    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub tbxTimePicker1_Enter()
    
    With Me.tbxTimePicker1
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = 2
    End With
    
    mtmPosition1 = tmPositionHour1
    
End Sub

Private Sub tbxTimePicker1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    
    If KeyCode = miRIGHTARROW1 Then
        If Me.IsHour1 Then
            SelectMinute1
        ElseIf Me.IsMinute1 Then
            SelectSecond1
        End If
    ElseIf KeyCode = miLEFTARROW1 Then
        If Me.IsSecond1 Then
            SelectMinute1
        Else
            SelectHour1
        End If
    Else
        If Me.IsHour1 Then
            SelectHour1
        ElseIf Me.IsMinute1 Then
            SelectMinute1
        ElseIf Me.IsSecond1 Then
            SelectSecond1
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub tbxTimePicker1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    
    If Me.tbxTimePicker1.SelStart < 3 Then
        SelectHour1
    ElseIf Me.tbxTimePicker1.SelStart < 6 Then
        SelectMinute1
    ElseIf Me.tbxTimePicker1.SelStart < 9 Then
        SelectSecond1
    End If
    
End Sub



Public Property Get IsHour1() As Boolean
    
    IsHour1 = mtmPosition1 = tmPositionHour1
    
End Property

Public Property Get IsMinute1() As Boolean
    
    IsMinute1 = mtmPosition1 = tmPositionMinute1
    
End Property

Public Property Get IsSecond1() As Boolean
    
    IsSecond1 = mtmPosition1 = tmPositionSecond1
    
End Property


Private Sub SelectMinute1()
    
    With Me.tbxTimePicker1
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = 3
        .SelLength = 2
    End With
    
    mtmPosition1 = tmPositionMinute1
    
End Sub

Private Sub SelectHour1()
    
    With Me.tbxTimePicker1
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = 2
    End With
    
    mtmPosition1 = tmPositionHour1
    
End Sub

Private Sub SelectSecond1()
    
    With Me.tbxTimePicker1
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = 6
        .SelLength = 2
    End With

    mtmPosition1 = tmPositionSecond1
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to modify your code, I suggest to do as follows:

Let the user enter, with `SpinDown` and `SpinUp` controls the "process duration" as three numbers (integers), 0-99 (hours), 0-59 (minutes) and 0-59 (seconds). Do not treat these as time values, just simple numbers.

If applicable, let the user enter "process start time", use separate `SpinDown/SpinUp` controls as true time values.

If applicable, to show "process end time" use simple text boxes to show start time + duration as calculated end time (day, hour, minute, second)